# Hide part of URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an autogenerated URL. Example:

https://domain.com/folder/login/confirm.php?data=ujOeNXV3cVxuljf/username

This URL is automatically generated by the user registration on a moodle platform and I want to change it so that the final parameters are not shown. Something like this:

https://domain.com/folder/login/confirm.php

or

https://domain.com/folder/login

How can I do this in my .htaccess? I have Apache WS 2.4 and Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you don't want them to see the token in the address bar?

What you can do is in confirm.php, if it comes in as a GET request, resend it back to confirm.php as a POST.  It will only show in the address bar then initially when it is processed

So something like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["data"]){
$url = 'https://domain.com/folder/login/confirm.php';
$data = array('data' => $_GET["data"]);



// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);

} else {

// if it's not set then you continue processing

}
?>
```